# Create class library in MSVS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

How to create simple class library using C++ from Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Enterprise ? I do File->new->project->visual C++-> and in this place there is only one class library under section CLR. I don't need .NET things. I need just simple c++ class library. I'm following article  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319950/Creating-your-own-library-in-visual-studio.

Comment: Pick Win32 Project instead.  At the next wizard step, pick Static library.

Comment: But I need class library

Comment: You can put free functions in a static library. Or you can put nothing but classes in a static library. Which now entitles you to call it "class library", let your imagination be your guide.